# Measure Execution ASP.NET time without network time

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis, logging, measure

I would like to measure the request execution time of my MVC .NET4.5 App.
With IIS logging, the time-taken filed include the network time. (https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/944884)
I use IIS7.5 on Windows 2008 R2.

Is it possible (with IIS or another tool) to measure the time from the client request until the IIS response ? (and without waits for the client to acknowledge)

Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmmm sound like to create an action filter ? like this

```
public class CheckTimeFilter : IActionFilter
{
    private Stopwatch stopWatch = new Stopwatch();

    public void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        stopWatch.Reset();
        stopWatch.Start();
    }

    public void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext filterContext)
    {
        stopWatch.Stop();
        var executionTime = stopWatch.ElapsedMilliseconds;
        // Do something with the executionTime
    }
}
```

and register this filter to Global filter in `Application_Start()'

```
GlobalFilters.Filters.Add(new CheckTimeFilter());
```

I also would like to suggest you to [**VISIT**](http://weblogs.asp.net/imranbaloch/page-instrumentation-in-asp-net-4-5)  and also [**THIS**](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2014/07/29/profile-and-time-your-asp-net-mvc-app-all-the-way-to-azure.aspx)

Comment: Thanks!, but I was thinking more of a tool to connect to IIS. Is a tool like this exists?

Comment: after further research, the solution is implements a watcher like the Usman's answer (thanks :) and plug a monitoring tool inside the LAN network (a server inside the Datacenter)